# How to specify response headers to CORS?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, jwt

I am building a backend REST API in spring and my friend is building a Angular JS front end app to call my API.I have a token header with key `Authorization` and a value which gives access to the service otherwise it refuses.From Postman and REST client I am able to receive the API but when tested he says he gets 401 Unauthorized Error on preflight.Below is my doFilterInternal method.

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, Authorization");
}
```

But when he calls the API with the token in Angular JS he gets

So I followed this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221602/response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-401-angular) and I added the property

`spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true`

in the application.properties.But stillt he error seems to be like

**Response for preflight has invalid https status code 401**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the filter which avoid the preflight error

```
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            LOG.info("Adding CORS Headers ........................");        
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
            res.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
            if ("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
             res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            } else { 
             chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }        
        }
```

Found it from the post [Cross Origin Request Blocked Spring MVC Restful Angularjs](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-mvc-tutorial/cross-origin-request-blocked-spring-mvc-restful-angularjs.html)

Comment: Now it throws a different error as `Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Comment: Sound like this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862579/request-header-field-access-control-allow-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-contro?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

this can help you, Spring have differents way to configure Cors headers
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question with `jwt`, I almost feel obligated to suggest this excellent [demo](https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo) on spring boot and jwt.

The project includes some useful Security configuration.

Unfortunately it does not configure cors but here are two ways to *quickly* fix your problem:

The easiest way I know of is to annotate a `RestController` with `@CrossOrigin("*")`

The second option is to configure cors with spring security:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.cors();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource () {

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source;
        source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        List<String> all = Collections.singletonList("*");
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(all);
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(all);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(all);

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;

    }

}
```

**Disclaimer**

It's quite obvious that both approaches will allow everything. That's fine during development but a terrible idea when used in production code!

Comment: And what should be solution in production mode?